# Can this xpath be simplified?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have this code:

```
<!--Display the name of the brother assigned-->
<xsl:template match="Name | PrayerOpen | PrayerEnd">
  <td class="cellName">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="//MeetingWorkBook/Settings/ForeignGroupMode='1' and (
                 ../@BookmarkId='2' or ../../@BookmarkId='2' or 
                 ../../../@BookmarkId='2'or ../../../../@BookmarkId='2' or 
                 ../@BookmarkId='4' or ../../@BookmarkId='4' or 
                 ../../../@BookmarkId='4' or ../../../../@BookmarkId='4' or 
                 self::PrayerOpen or self::PrayerEnd)">
        <em><xsl:value-of select ="//Labels/MainHall"/></em>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="//MeetingWorkBook/Settings/ForeignGroupMode='1' and .='' and self::Name">
        <em><xsl:value-of select ="//Labels/MainHall"/></em>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@Duplicate=1">
        <span class="textDuplicate">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```

It works fine. I have a series of paths so that I can find the correct node which has the `BookmarkId` attribute. Can this code be simplified?

Basically, based on the context of the current node I want to walk up the parents until it hits the `Meeting` node which is the one with the attribute.

## Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk-FGroup-v2.xsl"?>
<MeetingWorkBook>
    <Meeting BookmarkId="0" PageBreak="0" NumberClasses="1" SpecialEvent="0">
        <PrayerOpen>Name 1</PrayerOpen>
        <TFGW NumberClasses="1">
            <TFGWItem>
                <Name>Name 2</Name>
            </TFGWItem>
            <TFGWItem>
                <Name>Name 3</Name>
            </TFGWItem>
        </TFGW>
        <AYFM NumberClasses="1">
            <Teaching>
                <Name>Name 4</Name>
            </Teaching>
        </AYFM>
        <LAC CircuitVisit="0">
            <LACItem>
                <Name>Name 5</Name>
            </LACItem>
            <PrayerEnd>Name 6</PrayerEnd>
        </LAC>
    </Meeting>
</MeetingWorkBook>
```

Comment: Why don't you show an example XML so you can get an intelligent answer. Offhand, it seems you're looking for `ancestor::*/@BookmarkId`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks, so if I want to find the first `Meeting` element with this attribute that has a value of 2 I would use `ancestor::Meeting[@BookmarkId='2']`.

Comment: Actually, that would find **all** ancestor `Meeting` elements that satisfy the condition. To find the first among them, you would use `ancestor::Meeting[@BookmarkId='2'][1]` - with the caveat that "first" on the `ancestor` axis means the closest to the current node.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have added example XML for one `Meeting` with required content to see the context of the 3 elements caught by the template. In all instances there will **only be one** ancestor that is a `Meeting` node for them.

Comment: In your example, `Name`, `PrayerOpen` and `PrayerEnd` all have a single `Meeting` ancestor, so testing the value of `ancestor::Meeting/@BookmarkId` would work for all 3 alike. To make this more efficient, you could test at the `Meeting` level and pass down the result as a parameter.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am just trying to keep the changes that users would need to make to a minimum, but thanks for the suggestion. Question, you don't use the square braces `[...]` but I will need these if I am testing against specific values won't I?

Comment: Well, in the given scenario `<xsl:when test="ancestor::Meeting/@BookmarkId = 2">` and  `<xsl:when test="ancestor::Meeting[@BookmarkId = 2]">` would return the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the advice in the comments I have ended up using the `ancestor` call. So my template now looks like this:

```xml
  <!--Display the name of the brother assigned-->
  <xsl:template match="Name | PrayerOpen | PrayerEnd">
    <td class="cellName">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//MeetingWorkBook/Settings/ForeignGroupMode='1' and (
                        ancestor::Meeting[@BookmarkId='2'] or 
                        ancestor::Meeting[@BookmarkId='4'] or self::PrayerOpen or self::PrayerEnd)">
          <em><xsl:value-of select ="//Labels/MainHall"/></em>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="//MeetingWorkBook/Settings/ForeignGroupMode='1' and .='' and self::Name">
          <em><xsl:value-of select ="//Labels/MainHall"/></em>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@Duplicate=1">
          <span class="textDuplicate">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```